# How to pass secure_auth to MySQL login via SQLalchemy

Tags: mysql, pyramid, mysql-python

I'm working on the front end of a webapp, and my co-developer is using Pyramid and SQAlchemy. We've just moved from SQLite to MySQL. I installed MySQL 5.6.15 (via Homebrew) on my OS X machine to get the Python MySQLdb install to work (via pip in a virtualenv).

Because in MySQL >= 5.6.5 `secure_auth` is now `ON` by default I can only connect to the remote database (pre 5.6.5) with the `--skip-secure-auth` flag, which works fine in a terminal.

However, in the Python Pyramid code, it only seems possible to add this flag as [an argument to `create_engine()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html?highlight=mysql%20connection%20url#custom-dbapi-connect-arguments), but I can't find `create_engine()` in my co-dev's code, only the connection string below in an initialisation config file. He's not available, this isn't my area of expertise, and we launch next week :(

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+mysqldb://gooddeeds:deeds808letme1now@146.227.24.38/gooddeeds_development?charset=utf8
```

I've tried appending various ["secure auth" strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_secure-auth) to the above with no success. Am I looking in the wrong place? Has MySQLdb set `secure_auth` to `ON` because I'm running MySQL 5.6.15? If so, how can I change that?

Comment: Do you have the exact error message from the MySQL server? I'm not sure that secure_auth has much to do with it. If you still are using insecure, old-passwords (from pre-4.1), you you _definitely_ have change that right now.

Comment: It was the well-known "Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused..." however, we can't make changes to MySQL on the server. I *can* log in on the command line with the --skip-secure-auth flag, which I admit should only be a temporary solution. For now, I need to do the same via SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are forced to use the old passwords (bah!) when using MySQL 5.6, and using MySQLdb with SQLAlchemy, you'll have to add the --skip-secure-auth to an option file and use URL:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

..

dialect_options = {
  'read_default_file': '/path/to/your/mysql.cnf',
}

engine = create_engine(URL(
  'mysql',
  username='..', password='..',
  host='..', database='..',
  query=dialect_options
  ))
```

The mysql.cnf would contain:

```
[client]
skip-secure-auth
```

**For Pyramid**, you can do the following. Add a line in your configuration ini-file that holds the connection arguments:

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test
sqlalchemy.connect_args = { 'read_default_file': '/path/to/foo' }
```

Now you need to change a bit the way the settings are read and used. In the file that launches your Pyramic app, do the following:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    try:
        settings['sqlalchemy.connect_args'] = eval(settings['sqlalchemy.connect_args'])
    except KeyError:
        settings['sqlalchemy.connect_args'] = {}
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    # rest of code..
```

The trick is to evaluate the string in the ini file which contains a dictionary with the extra options for the SQLAlchemy dialect.

Comment: How does this work in pyramid where we are using `engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')`? - (co-developer)

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution for Pyramid.